# align icons to dictionary entries

Tags: tables, graphics, positioning, marginpar

I'm trying to typeset a small dictionary. Many of the entries come with a couple of icons that I would like to display in the margin just left of the entry, top-aligned with the beginning of the entry.

I hacked together a solution using tabular and lots of vspace/hspace but it all became a horrible mess and is really hard to change if I want to adjust any spacing or sizes. There must be a better way - can anyone point me towards a package or paradigm useful for this?

For some entries the icons take more vertical space than the text entry itself and spacing between entries should be adjusted.

Comment: look at package `marginnote`

Comment: It depends on your implementation. Perhaps you could do it with `\llap`. For example, use `\llap{\makebox[2cm]{hi}}Text.` at the left hand side of the text block. You can also define your own `list` environment that uses a similar technique. It would be useful if you could provide a minimal example.

Comment: if using `\llap`, it should most likely be preceded by `\leavevmode`.  also, since some of these icons take more vertical space than the text entries, `\smash{...}` should be applied to the box or its contents.  (an actual example would make this easier to explain.)